# Unable to run ReactNative app on IOS simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator

I am working on a ReactNative app on Mac. I have installed the XCode 6. I go to the XCode -> Open Developer Tool -> IOS Simulator. This starts a simulator, now when i run the following command on VS Code terminal

```
react-native run-ios
```

i get the following error

```
info Found Xcode project "MyNewProject.xcodeproj"
Usage: simctl list [devices|devicetypes|runtimes]
error Could not parse the simulator list output. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: xcrun simctl list --json devices
Usage: simctl list [devices|devicetypes|runtimes]

at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
at runOnSimulator (/Users/ssi/Desktop/ReactNativeApp/MyNewProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:129:30)
at Object.runIOS [as func] (/Users/ssi/Desktop/ReactNativeApp/MyNewProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:97:12)
at Command.handleAction (/Users/ssi/Desktop/ReactNativeApp/MyNewProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/cliEntry.js:160:21)
at Command.listener (/Users/ssi/Desktop/ReactNativeApp/MyNewProject/node_modules/commander/index.js:315:8)
at Command.emit (events.js:198:13)
at Command.parseArgs (/Users/ssi/Desktop/ReactNativeApp/MyNewProject/node_modules/commander/index.js:651:12)
at Command.parse (/Users/ssi/Desktop/ReactNativeApp/MyNewProject/node_modules/commander/index.js:474:21)
at setupAndRun (/Users/ssi/Desktop/ReactNativeApp/MyNewProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/cliEntry.js:210:24)
```

I have googled a lot but could not find anything helpful. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 6 is 5 years old.  I believe --json was added to simctl in Xcode 8 or Xcode 8.  You will need a newer version of CoreSimulator from a newer Xcode if you want to use that.